What is the git issue that causes a bunch of commits already on master to be pushed to a pull request from a feature branch
I often see this in pull requests, where someone accidentally pushes up a bunch of rebased commits into their PR, and then in the commits tab, there's a long list of all the existing commits that are already on master.
I remember I had this issue when I was a git newby and messed up rebases (I don't think the issue was present with merge), but I can't recall what caused the issue. Does anyone know what I'm referring to?

For the 2 peopel that voted to close on grounds that it needs more details. What clarifications/details are you looking for?

Do you have a specific example?

I think this question is perfectly clear and no new details are needed. Note though there isn't "the" single git issue that causes it, but there are definitely the big hitters that do.

you should ask the author of that branch what exactly they are doing. there's a lot of unknowns

I see this too sometimes, and here are some common causes for it:

When someone branches off of one shared branch (e.g. develop), and creates a PR into another shared branch (e.g. master or release), and creates a PR, the initial view of that PR is oftentimes going to show far more commits than it should. If they then try to fix this by rebasing (maybe with a rebase --onto which went badly), they might accidentally rewrite many commits on their branch that are already on a shared branch.
When a feature branch has conflicts or you just wish to update it with the latest master, you may choose to rebase your feature branch onto the latest version of master. But if you accidentally rebase your local copy of master onto the feature branch, you will rewrite the wrong branch, and some UI tools make it pretty easy to click this option. At this point it does take an additional step to get those commits into the feature branch, but somehow novices tend to accidentally do this as well, perhaps by merging that branch into their feature branch, or then turning around and rebasing their feature branch onto the newly rewritten master.
When rewriting your own branch, perhaps interactively to squash or update local commits, sometimes people like to use the parent syntax, such as git rebase HEAD~10 to rewrite the last 10 commits on their branch. Oftentimes the 11th commit is a merge commit, from the last PR that was completed into master at the time they created their branch. So if you accidentally go back 1 commit to far, e.g. git rebase HEAD~11, then you will end up rebasing your 10 commits plus all of the commits on master that were brought in by the 11th merge commit. Then all those commits will show up in the PR as well.

Possible tips to help prevent this:

In some repositories where we use a rebase workflow, we urge our developers to commit early and often, but also to clean them up and make a minimal number of useful commits before creating (or at least completing) their Pull Request. We put a gated checkin that will fail if the PR has more than 5 new commits in it, and less than 1% of Pull Requests need manual intervention because the developer wanted to have more than that. The vast majority of the time when someone has more than 5 commits in the PR, it's due to one of the problems described above, and with the gate failing it forces them to notice the issue and fix it.
We urge people to not check out local copies of master, and to always fetch and use origin/master instead. This pretty much eliminates the possibility of #2, and also reduces conflicts overall due to people accidentally creating new work based off of old local copies of master.


Thanks for sharing. I'm really not sure which of those, if any, occurred. I was trying to reproduce this issue today and couldn't. In my early days of using git, this happened frequently, and nowadays, I only see it happening in other people's PRs at work. The general workflow at where I work is as follows. 1) Create feature branch and make your changes. 2) Rebase/merge (I usually rebase but some people use merge) on top of origin master 3) push.
